# HttpPost return a json string different respect the one of the browser

Tags: android, json, post, https

When I go to

> https://api.github.com/users/jkirkell/gists

I receive a json with good data.

**i.e**

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/gists/5143977",
    "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/5143977/forks",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/5143977/commits",
    "id": "5143977",
    etc.
```

But if I read the SAME address with this code:

```
String jsonString = null;
InputStream is = null;

HttpResponse response = null;
try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://api.github.com/users/jkirkell/gists");
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
}catch(Exception e){
        throw e;
}
```

I receive this json string:

```
{"message":"Not Found"}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `HttpGet` instead of `HttpPost`:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://api.github.com/users/jkirkell/gists");
response = httpclient.execute(request);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is `Get` Request but you are using HTTP post.

Try to read like this

int k=0;

```
   URL url = new URL(yoururl);
         InputStream input=url1.openStream();
         BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(input);
         ByteArrayBuffer baf=new ByteArrayBuffer(1000);
         while((k=bis.read())!=-1)
         {
         baf.append((byte)k);
         }
        String data=new String(baf.toByteArray());
```